# Stripe payment change data-currency attribute using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, stripe-payments

I have implemented stripe payment using stripe popup but before open this popup we need to set data-currency based on customer selection of currency suppose "USD" OR "EUR".

I tried with this code :

```
$('#custom_currency').change(function() {
  $('.stripe-button').data('currency', $(this).val());
});
```

I checked in console and data-currency value change but in stripe popup always display the $.

Right now i select Euro(EUR) but always display $. (http://prntscr.com/kisgdt)

Would you please let me know what is the issue.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need to use Custom Checkout for this. The approach is to provide the selected currency value when calling the `open()` function on your `handler` [1] so it can be set at the time the pop up is opened.

Here's an example that should show the approach to take:
https://jsfiddle.net/m07esujc/

[1] the `handler` that you get when initializing Checkout with `StripeCheckout.configure()`

Comment: Sorry, but if you have code please send me becuase i already checked with this and no luck so if you have any other way then please let me know. Thanks

Comment: @InSystemGrp: I provided an example in the answer. Here it is:  https://jsfiddle.net/m07esujc/